# Laravel named routes with my domain name without using the port

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 9 and I am deploying my web in a windows VPC with IIS server. How do I change my named route variable to my domain, without the port.

Here is my route web.php

```
Route::get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register_view'])->name('register_view')->middleware(HasToken::class);
```

In my public view page I use the route in my hyperlinks like this

```
home.blade.php
<a href="{{ route('register_view') }}">Register</a>
```

The I use the cmd php artisan serve --host="mywebsite.com" --port=3000

*I have to use other port besides 80

Website at my domain load the page perfectly, but my links hrefs are using http://localhost:3000
[image]

How do I change this named route settings to be my domain?

I have changed all the constant such as APP_URL in .env to my domain

Have tried using Route::domain("mywebsite.com")->group(function() { /* My routes */ }), but in the web it becomes http://mywebsite.com:3000/routes (it appended my local internal port and also without https), how do I configure this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if port 80 is in use by something else then you cannot remove the port number from the url.  Only use artisan serve for development, never for production.  You say you use IIS server, then you should not need to use artisan serve anyway. Use IIS.  You will need to find out how to host multiple sites using the domain name to indicate which site you want to access.

Comment: did you put the APP_URL= http://mywebsite.com  in .env file?

Comment: hello @Snapey , thanks for your help, I have tried to use IIS to point to the directory straight away, the named routes have use the correct domain, but it is using http rather than https, how do I configure to use https?

Comment: @BholaKr.Khawas yes I did

Comment: You have to install SSL certificate.  Sorry. I can't help with IIS and to be honest you are a bit out on a limb using IIS as it is extremely uncommon (for PHP sites)  I guess there are some enthusiasts that might be able to help.

Comment: Yeah, for some specific reasons we can only use IIS for this, thanks a lot man!